# A defaultProps element considered undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm trying to practice a bit of routes and routing, and I'm facing some issues I haven't been able to solve.

My error seem to be taking place in render method in `App.js`.

Things are quite straight-forward. I'm trying to create a `getDogFunc` which is supposed to assist me with finding a certain element depending on the given route/URL.

I seem to get error when attempting to accessing the array existing in the `defaultProps`. For some odd reason, it is being seen as `undefined`, and I didn't quite understand why.

The code:

**App.js**

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import Dog from './Dog';
import DogList from './DogList';
import hazel from "./_images/hazel.jpg";
import whiskey from "./_images/whiskey.jpg";
import tubby from "./_images/tubby.jpg";
import { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component {
  static defaultProps = {
    dogs: [
      {
        name: "Whiskey",
        age: 5,
        src: whiskey,
        facts: [
          "Whiskey loves eating popcorn.",
          "Whiskey is a terrible guard dog.",
          "Whiskey wants to cuddle with you!"
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "Hazel",
        age: 3,
        src: hazel,
        facts: [
          "Hazel has soooo much energy!",
          "Hazel is highly intelligent.",
          "Hazel loves people more than dogs."
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "Tubby",
        age: 4,
        src: tubby,
        facts: [
          "Tubby is not the brightest dog",
          "Tubby does not like walks or exercise.",
          "Tubby loves eating food."
        ]
      }
    ]
  }

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }
  
  render(){
    const getDogFunc = (props) => { // it's the same props which will derive from the URL /dog/:name
      let name = props.match.params.name;
      console.log("HAZELLL");
      console.log(props.dogs)
      let currentDog = props.dogs.find(dog => (dog.name.toLowerCase() === name.toLowerCase()))
      return <DogList {...props} dogs={currentDog}/>;
    };

  return (
    <div className="App">

      <Switch>
      <Route
      exact
      path="/dog/:name"
      render={getDogFunc} //This route sends automatically props into getDogFunc as a parameter
      />
      <Route
      exact
      path="/"
      render={(routeProps)=> <DogList {...routeProps} dogs={this.defaultProps.dogs}/>}
      />
    
    </Switch>
    </div>
    
  );
}
}

export default App;
```

**DogList.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Dog from './Dog'
import './DogList.css';
export default class DogList extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
            <div className='display-1 text-center DogList-title'>
                Dog List!
            </div>
            <div className='container'>
                <div className='row'>
                    
                    {this.props.dogs.map
                    (dog=><div className='col-lg-4'>
                    <Dog 
                    name={dog.name}
                    age={dog.age}
                    srcimg={dog.src}
                    fact={dog.facts}
                    key={dog.name}
                    id={dog.name}
                    />
                    </div>
                    )}  
                    
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
   
    )
  }
}
```

**Dog.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import './Dog.css';

export default class Dog extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }

    handleClick(){
        //do something need to load page of the chosen dog - need to set for him a key.
        alert(`CLICKED ON ${this.props.id}`)
        //use history to push and forward to to props.name
        this.props.history.push(`/dog/${this.props.id}`);
    }
    render() {
    return (
    <div className='Dog'>
        <div className='Dog-img'>
            <img src={this.props.srcimg}/>
        </div>
        <div className='display-5 text-center Dog-name hover-underline-animation'>
            <p onClick={this.handleClick}>{this.props.name}</p>
        </div>
        <div className='Dog-info'>
            <p>
                {/* Age: {this.props.age}<br/><br/>
                Facts: {this.props.fact.map((f) => <> {f} <br/> </>)} */}
            </p> 
        </div>
      
    </div>
    )
  }
}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

- `defaultProps` are just that, props, so accessing them is the same for accessing the props object anywhere else in a React class component, i.e. `this.props.dogs`.
- In the `getDogFunc` the "props" that are passed to the `render` function are the [route props](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-props), i.e. `history`, `location`, and `match`. If you are trying to filter the `dogs` array then it's still a prop of the outer `App` component, i.e. `this.props.dogs`.
- `DogList` is expecting the `dogs` prop to be an array, so when passing the `dogs` prop when on route `path="/dog/:name"` you should *`.filter`* the array instead of using `.find` so an array is passed to `DogList` and the `dogs` prop can still be mapped.
- The `Dog` component isn't rendered directly by a `Route` nor is it decorated with the [`withRouter`](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter) Higher Order Component, so `this.props.history` is undefined.
- When mapping the `dogs` array in `DogList` each mapped element needs a React key. Note that the provided key should be on the ***outermost*** element being mapped.

## Solution

### Dog

Inject the route props into the `Dog` component.

```
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

class DogBase extends Component {
  handleClick = () => {
    //do something need to load page of the chosen dog - need to set for him a key.
    alert(`CLICKED ON ${this.props.id}`);
    //use history to push and forward to to props.name
    this.props.history.push(`/dog/${this.props.id}`);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Dog">
        <div className="Dog-img">
          <img alt="dog" src={this.props.srcimg} />
        </div>
        <div className="display-5 text-center Dog-name hover-underline-animation">
          <p onClick={this.handleClick}>{this.props.name}</p>
        </div>
        <div className="Dog-info">
          <p>
            {/* Age: {this.props.age}<br/><br/>
                Facts: {this.props.fact.map((f) => <> {f} <br/> </>)} */}
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(DogBase);
```

### DogList

```
class DogList extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="display-1 text-center DogList-title">Dog List!</div>
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
            {this.props.dogs.map((dog) => (
              <div key={dog.name} className="col-lg-4"> // <-- React key here
                <Dog
                  name={dog.name}
                  age={dog.age}
                  srcimg={dog.src}
                  fact={dog.facts}
                  id={dog.name}
                />
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

### App

Access the dogs array via `this.props.dogs`, and pass a filtered `dogs` array to the `DogsList` component.

```
class App extends Component {
  static defaultProps = {
    dogs: [
      {
        name: "Whiskey",
        age: 5,
        src: whiskey,
        facts: [
          "Whiskey loves eating popcorn.",
          "Whiskey is a terrible guard dog.",
          "Whiskey wants to cuddle with you!"
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "Hazel",
        age: 3,
        src: hazel,
        facts: [
          "Hazel has soooo much energy!",
          "Hazel is highly intelligent.",
          "Hazel loves people more than dogs."
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "Tubby",
        age: 4,
        src: tubby,
        facts: [
          "Tubby is not the brightest dog",
          "Tubby does not like walks or exercise.",
          "Tubby loves eating food."
        ]
      }
    ]
  };

  // constructor(props) {
  //   super(props);
  // }

  render() {
    const getDogFunc = (props) => {
      // it's the same props which will derive from the URL /dog/:name
      const { name } = props.match.params;
      console.log("HAZELLL");
      console.log(this.props.dogs);
      const currentDog = this.props.dogs.filter(
        (dog) => dog.name.toLowerCase() === name.toLowerCase()
      );
      return <DogList {...props} dogs={currentDog} />;
    };

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Switch>
          <Route
            path="/dog/:name"
            render={getDogFunc} //This route sends automatically props into getDogFunc as a parameter
          />
          <Route
            path="/"
            render={(routeProps) => (
              <DogList {...routeProps} dogs={this.props.dogs} />
            )}
          />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Edit a-defaultprops-element-considered-undefined]

## Alternative Solution

Make the `default` `dogs` prop a default on the `DogList` component and use the `name` route param to filter the `dogs` array prop inline when rendering.

Example:

DogList

```
class DogList extends Component {
  static defaultProps = {
    dogs: [
      {
        name: "Whiskey",
        age: 5,
        src: whiskey,
        facts: [
          "Whiskey loves eating popcorn.",
          "Whiskey is a terrible guard dog.",
          "Whiskey wants to cuddle with you!"
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "Hazel",
        age: 3,
        src: hazel,
        facts: [
          "Hazel has soooo much energy!",
          "Hazel is highly intelligent.",
          "Hazel loves people more than dogs."
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "Tubby",
        age: 4,
        src: tubby,
        facts: [
          "Tubby is not the brightest dog",
          "Tubby does not like walks or exercise.",
          "Tubby loves eating food."
        ]
      }
    ]
  };

  render() {
    const {
      match: {
        params: { name = "" }
      }
    } = this.props;
    const searchName = name.toLowerCase();

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="display-1 text-center DogList-title">Dog List!</div>
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
            {this.props.dogs
              .filter((dog) => {
                if (searchName) {
                  return dog.name.toLowerCase() === searchName;
                }
                return true;
              })
              .map((dog) => (
                <div key={dog.name} className="col-lg-4">
                  <Dog
                    name={dog.name}
                    age={dog.age}
                    srcimg={dog.src}
                    fact={dog.facts}
                    id={dog.name}
                  />
                </div>
              ))}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

App

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Switch>
          <Route path={["/dog/:name", "/"]} component={DogList} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Edit a-defaultprops-element-considered-undefined (forked)]